# Missing _this definition

Tags: typescript

I have a function defined in a object like this:

```
    connect(callback?: (connected: bool) => void) {
        $.ajax(this.url + "/connect", $.extend(true, {}, this.ajaxSettings, {
            success: (data) => {
                this.errorChecker(data, (data) => {
                    if (callback != null) {
                        callback(data);
                    }
                });
            },
            timeout: this.timeout,
            error: () => {
                if (callback != null) {
                    callback(false);
                }
            }
        }));
    }
```

The TypeScript compiler takes that and produces this:

```
        VAS.prototype.connect = function (callback) {
            $.ajax(this.url + "/connect", $.extend(true, {
            }, this.ajaxSettings, {
                success: function (data) {
                    _this.errorChecker(data, function (data) {
                        if(callback != null) {
                            callback(data);
                        }
                    });
                },
                timeout: this.timeout,
                error: function () {
                    if(callback != null) {
                        callback(false);
                    }
                }
            }));
        };
```

Note this line in the js:

`_this.errorChecker(data, function (data)`

The compiler has correctly noticed my use of the => operator and concluded that `this` in my original TypeScript should refer to the parent object and not whatever `this` happens to be when the success callback is actually called. But, for some reason the compiler has forgotten to include the magic line:

```
var _this = this;
```

At the start of the function. Is this a bug? Or is this by design? If it just ignored the _this / this thing altogether, I'd just say I'm doing it wrong, but it's going half way here which makes me think something is wrong.

**Update**: oddly this seems to be a problem with the compiler in Visual Studio, if I copy the same code into the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/) it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug. You should open a [work item](http://typescript.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create) to track this.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too, but I always like to make sure I'm not missing something obvious first. I submitted a bug [here](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/181).